# JavaScript - display a message when scroll to div

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, alert

My site is horizontal. If I move a scroll to right on the div "contact" I would like to function returns a value, it can be alert.

Comment: do you use jQuery? or just pure javascript

Comment: @Edd Please show us your Java script code

Answer (score 1):

jQuery:

```
$("#contact-container").scroll(function(){
    alert($(this).scrollLeft());
});
```

Pure JS:

```
var box = document.getElementById('box');
box.onscroll = function () {
    alert(this.scrollLeft);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this using jQuery framework

var var oldScrollLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();

$(window).scroll(function () {

```
    if(oldScrollLeft!= $(window).scrollLeft()){

       //function here

     }

 });​
```